# Looking for a Fedora 21 repository for current GNU Emacs development code

Tags: emacs-development

I'm asking here as I can't find it anywhere on the net: I was about to learn how Emacs is actually packaged for Fedora 21 (btw, thanks a lot to the maintainers) to do the same with the latest release, but if that's already done there's not much purpose on reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Do you intend to rebuild nightly? I'd be _very_ interested in this.

Comment: If by weekend I have no answer I will try and do my best, and post the resulting RPM (or repo) back here.

Comment: I already started looking at this, will post back when I have something to show you guys.